# How to properly call a method when setting a property in PHP (if even possible)

Tags: php, oop, class

I'm wondering why this doesn't work? I'm setting a property (array) and one value it has to get from a method inside the class, I guess I'm doing something I really shouldn't but I would be very grateful for both an explanation why it doesn't work and how it would work ;)

I'm new to

```
 Class Widget{

    public $settings = array('setting1',array(
    'subsetting1'=> 1, 
    'subsetting2' =>$this->WidgetFunction()
    ));

             function WidgetFunction() {
             echo 'works';
             }
}
```

Getting following error:

```
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE on line 7 
(where WidgetFunction is called)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> Class member variables are called "properties". [...] They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. **This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value**--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

You should assign this value in your [constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

```
Class Widget {

  public $settings;

  function __construct() {
    $this->settings = array(
      'setting1' => array(
        'subsetting1' => 1, 
        'subsetting2' => $this->WidgetFunction())
    );
  }

  function WidgetFunction() {
    echo 'works';
  }
}
```

(btw, I think you might have wanted to use 'setting1' as an index for the array in the array - as I did it in my code example?)

Comment: Great, thank you so much, also for the code correction, much appreciated!